# Meteor Mup Fails - npm install --unsafe-perm returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor, mup

Although it was working yesterday, I now get an error when deploying my Meteor app to Digital Ocean via Mup.

I get the following error:

`The command '/bin/sh -c cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm' returned a non-zero code: 1`

My mup file is:

```
module.exports = {
    servers: {
        one: {
            host: '134.209.106.xx',
            username: 'XXX',
            password: 'XXX',
        }
    },
    app: {
        // TODO: change app name and path
        name: 'masters-of-the-modern-age',
        path: '../',
        volumes: {
            '/uploads': '/uploads'
        },
        servers: {
            one: {},
        },
        buildOptions: {
            serverOnly: true
        },
        env: {
            ROOT_URL: 'https://app.skill.social'
        },
        docker: {
            image: 'abernix/meteord:node-12.16.1-base'
        },
        enableUploadProgressBar: true,
        deployCheckWaitTime: 100
    },
    proxy: {
        domains: 'app.skill.social',
        ssl: {
            letsEncryptEmail: 'hello@soma.academy',
            forceSSL: true
        }
    },
    mongo: {
        version: '3.4.1',
        servers: {
            one: {}
        }
    },
};
```

The mup deploy --verbose output is:

```
Building App Bundle Locally
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`

Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor App
[134.209.106.56] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server
[134.209.106.56] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server: SUCCESS
[134.209.106.56] - Prepare Bundle
node-12.16.1-base: Pulling from abernix/meteord
3192219afd04: Pulling fs layer
467dbb3d2aa9: Pulling fs layer
839371370b5e: Pulling fs layer
20de0707b26d: Pulling fs layer
6a8f7e3253aa: Pulling fs layer
37f7a255f4d5: Pulling fs layer
88a22e4d1eaf: Pulling fs layer
20de0707b26d: Waiting
6a8f7e3253aa: Waiting
37f7a255f4d5: Waiting
88a22e4d1eaf: Waiting
467dbb3d2aa9: Download complete
3192219afd04: Verifying Checksum
3192219afd04: Download complete
839371370b5e: Verifying Checksum
839371370b5e: Download complete
20de0707b26d: Verifying Checksum
20de0707b26d: Download complete
6a8f7e3253aa: Verifying Checksum
6a8f7e3253aa: Download complete
37f7a255f4d5: Verifying Checksum
37f7a255f4d5: Download complete
88a22e4d1eaf: Verifying Checksum
3192219afd04: Pull complete
467dbb3d2aa9: Pull complete
839371370b5e: Pull complete
20de0707b26d: Pull complete
6a8f7e3253aa: Pull complete
37f7a255f4d5: Pull complete
88a22e4d1eaf: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ce0b262902c9430230fd840fbef52690edcfdb3ba2c96015f83d310715c899f1
Status: Downloaded newer image for abernix/meteord:node-12.16.1-base
Finished Extracting
Creating Dockerfile
Finished creating Dockerfile
Building image
Sending build context to Docker daemon  347.1MB
Step 1/11 : FROM abernix/meteord:node-12.16.1-base
# Executing 1 build trigger
 ---> Running in 1598a5d00821
Removing intermediate container 1598a5d00821
 ---> 8621459a27f1
Step 2/11 : RUN mkdir /built_app || true
 ---> Running in 44753855e876
Removing intermediate container 44753855e876
 ---> 2a7026ff45c3
Step 3/11 : ENV ROOT_URL=https://app.skill.social
 ---> Running in 5adb91b3a44f
Removing intermediate container 5adb91b3a44f
 ---> 17cc71a78273
Step 4/11 : ENV MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/masters-of-the-modern-age
 ---> Running in e53bf91f7a57
Removing intermediate container e53bf91f7a57
 ---> cc2b884c45c7
Step 5/11 : ENV VIRTUAL_HOST=app.skill.social
 ---> Running in dd15986c49e9
Removing intermediate container dd15986c49e9
 ---> 7628af2ed3f8
Step 6/11 : ENV HTTPS_METHOD=redirect
 ---> Running in e29c63760b35
Removing intermediate container e29c63760b35
 ---> d5ef4136d224
Step 7/11 : ENV HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT=1
 ---> Running in 57888fe104cf
Removing intermediate container 57888fe104cf
 ---> eefa3fbfcdcf
Step 8/11 : ENV LETSENCRYPT_HOST=app.skill.social
 ---> Running in ee5c48488873
Removing intermediate container ee5c48488873
 ---> 50d677194fc4
Step 9/11 : ENV LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=hello@soma.academy
 ---> Running in 68f4325aee44
Removing intermediate container 68f4325aee44
 ---> e976998df6e3
Step 10/11 : COPY ./ /built_app
 ---> 5a9788e6f412
Step 11/11 : RUN cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm
 ---> Running in 10ce78e8688e
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error - GET https://codeload.github.com/meteor/node-source-map-support/legacy.tar.gz/1912478769d76e5df4c365e147f25896aee6375e

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-23T14_17_52_042Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm' returned a non-zero code: 1
[134.209.106.56] x Prepare Bundle: FAILED
```

I originally thought it was a mismatch in node versions as I recently updated Metoer, but `Meteor node -v` shows me I am on Node 12.16 and the docker image is set as the same.

Comment: So it worked before the Meteor core update?

Comment: Did you look into the npm logs to see if there was more info? `/root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-23T14_17_52_042Z-debug.log`